# ComplexType restriction in xsd

Tags: xsd

I am creating a XSD and defining ComplexType and want to know how to create restriction.

For example,

```
<xsd:complexType name="MyTestType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Country" type="xsd:string" > 
...
```

And, I want the element "Country" to be allowed 1 to 10 characters long.

Is there a way I can use minLength and maxLength on the element?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I got it from another post.

Comment: Hi Tony, to keep in line with SO recommendations, it would be nice to answer your question and mark it as answered, or remove the question all together if it is a duplicate of another one - which may be, since all you're asking after all may be/is how to restrict a simple type...

Comment: I suggest reading [W3 XSD Restrictions/Facets](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp), answers all your question on type restriction.

Answer (score 0):

The following code would do what you ask;

```
<xs:simpleType name="myTestType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="([a-z][A-Z])+"/>
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="10" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

You could simplify it and write the following;

```
<xs:simpleType name="myTestType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="([a-z][A-Z]){1-10}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```